# Construct line segment with enpoints on given circles and equal to given line segment

Tags: geometry, geometric-construction

Given a line $p$ and a line segment $\overline{MN}$ on $p$, and two circles $k_1$ and $k_2$, construct a line segment $\overline{AB}$ with endpoints on the circles so that $\overline{AB}$ is parallel to $p$ and the same length as $\overline{MN}$.

I can see that there is no solution if the circles are on different sides of the line $p$. But what would be the approach to do the construction when a solution exists?

Comment: Are the circles congruent?

Comment: @fleablood Nothing is known about the circles.

Comment: Hmmm.  this may not be helpful.  But make the line be (0,0) to (1,0).  Let the circles be $(x-a)^2 + (x-b)^2 = r^2$ and $(x-c)^2 + (x-d)^2 = s^2$  solve for $(x1,x2,y)$ where $(x1,y)$ is in one circle and $(x2,y)$ the other and $|x1 - x2| = 1$.  This are the points to find.  The solution will be some algebraic expression.  Translate those to constructions via finding proportional segments, parallel lines, inverse and square and square roots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just translate $k_1$ using $NM$ or $MN$ as vector in the direction of $k_2$

where this translated circle cuts $k_2$ are the points where the endpoints of $AB$ are (there can be two of them)